# Hibernate one to many mappedBy getting "invalid identifier

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, composite-key

Good day everyone! I have a class anmed `TeachingLocation` and it contains `TeachingLecturers`. I am trying to cascade TeachingLecturer and I am encountering ORA-00904 (Invalid identifier)

> The TeachingLocation class:

```
public class TeachingLocation extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /*
     * Column names.
     */
    public static final String COLUMN_TEACHING_ID = "TEACHING_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_ID = "LOCATION_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_PARTICIPANT_CEILING = "PARTICIPANT_CEILING";
    /*
     * Property names.
     */
    public static final String PROPERTY_TEACHING_ID = "teachingId";
    public static final String PROPERTY_LOCATION_ID = "locationId";
    public static final String PROPERTY_PARTICIPANT_CEILING = "participantCeiling";
    public static final String PROPERTY_TEACHING = "teaching";
    /*
     * Attributes.
     */
    private TeachingLocationId id;
    private Integer participantCeiling;
    /*
     * Related entities.
     */
    private Teaching teaching;
    private Location location;
    private List<TeachingLecturer> teachingLecturers;

    /**
     * Default construcotor.
     */
    public TeachingLocation() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId()
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = PROPERTY_TEACHING_ID, column =
        @Column(name = COLUMN_TEACHING_ID, length = 28)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = PROPERTY_LOCATION_ID, column =
        @Column(name = COLUMN_LOCATION_ID, length = 28))
    })
    public TeachingLocationId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(TeachingLocationId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = COLUMN_PARTICIPANT_CEILING, scale = 0, precision = 4)
    public Integer getParticipantCeiling() {
        return participantCeiling;
    }

    public void setParticipantCeiling(Integer participantCeiling) {
        this.participantCeiling = participantCeiling;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_TEACHING_ID, referencedColumnName=Teaching.COLUMN_ID, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @MapsId(PROPERTY_TEACHING_ID)
    public Teaching getTeaching() {
        return teaching;
    }

    public void setTeaching(Teaching teaching) {
        this.teaching = teaching;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_LOCATION_ID, referencedColumnName=Location.COLUMN_ADDRESS_OWNER_ID, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TeachingLocation{" + "id=" + id + ", participantCeiling=" + participantCeiling + '}';
    }

    /**
     * @return the teachingLecturers
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = TeachingLecturer.PROPERTY_TEACHING_LOCATION, targetEntity = TeachingLecturer.class, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    public List<TeachingLecturer> getTeachingLecturers() {
        return teachingLecturers;

    }

    public void setTeachingLecturers(List<TeachingLecturer> teachingLecturers) {
        this.teachingLecturers = teachingLecturers;
    }

}
```

> The TeachingLecturer class:

```
public class TeachingLecturer {

    public static final String PROPERTY_TEACHING_ID = "id.teachingId";
    public static final String PROPERTY_LOCATION_ID = "id.locationId";
    public static final String PROPERTY_LECTURER_ID = "lecturerId";
    public static final String PROPERTY_LECTURER = "lecturer";
    public static final String PROPERTY_TEACHING = "teaching";
    public static final String PROPERTY_TEACHING_LOCATION = "teachingLocation";

    public static final String COLUMN_TEACHING_ID = "TEACHING_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_ID = "LOCATION_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_LECTURER_ID = "LECTURER_ID";

    // Attributes
    private TeachingLecturerId id;

    // Relations
    private TeachingLocation teachingLocation;
    private Lecturer lecturer;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public TeachingLecturer() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param tlId
     */
    public TeachingLecturer(TeachingLecturerId tlId) {
        this.id = tlId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = PROPERTY_TEACHING_ID, column = @Column(name = COLUMN_TEACHING_ID, nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = PROPERTY_LOCATION_ID, column = @Column(name = COLUMN_LOCATION_ID, nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = PROPERTY_LECTURER_ID, column = @Column(name = COLUMN_LECTURER_ID, nullable = false))
    })
    public TeachingLecturerId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(TeachingLecturerId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the teachingLocation
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_TEACHING_ID, referencedColumnName = TeachingLocation.COLUMN_TEACHING_ID, updatable = false, insertable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_LOCATION_ID, referencedColumnName = TeachingLocation.COLUMN_LOCATION_ID, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    })
    @MapsId("id")
    public TeachingLocation getTeachingLocation() {
        return teachingLocation;
    }
    /**
     * @param teachingLocation the teachingLocation to set
     */
    public void setTeachingLocation(TeachingLocation teachingLocation) {
        this.teachingLocation = teachingLocation;
    }
    /**
     * @return the lecturer
     */
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Lecturer.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_LECTURER_ID, referencedColumnName = Lecturer.COLUMN_PERSON_ROLE_ID, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @MapsId("lecturerId")
    public Lecturer getLecturer() {
        return lecturer;
    }
    /**
     * @param lecturer the lecturer to set
     */
    public void setLecturer(Lecturer lecturer) {
        this.lecturer = lecturer;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TeachingLecturer [id=" + id + ", teachingLocation=" + teachingLocation + ", lecturer=" + lecturer + "]";
    }
}
```

> TeachingLecturerId:

```
public class TeachingLecturerId implements Serializable {
    private String teachingId;
    private String locationId;
    private String lecturerId;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public TeachingLecturerId() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param teachingId
     * @param locationId
     * @param lecturerId
     */
    public TeachingLecturerId(String teachingId, String locationId, String lecturerId) {
        this.teachingId = teachingId;
        this.locationId = locationId;
        this.lecturerId = lecturerId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the teachingId
     */
    public String getTeachingId() {
        return teachingId;
    }

    /**
     * @param teachingId
     *            the teachingId to set
     */
    public void setTeachingId(String teachingId) {
        this.teachingId = teachingId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the locationId
     */
    public String getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    /**
     * @param locationId
     *            the locationId to set
     */
    public void setLocationId(String locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lecturerId
     */
    public String getLecturerId() {
        return lecturerId;
    }

    /**
     * @param lecturerId
     *            the lecturerId to set
     */
    public void setLecturerId(String lecturerId) {
        this.lecturerId = lecturerId;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TeachingLecturerId [teachingId=" + teachingId + ", locationId=" + locationId + ", lecturerId="
                + lecturerId + "]";
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((lecturerId == null) ? 0 : lecturerId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((locationId == null) ? 0 : locationId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((teachingId == null) ? 0 : teachingId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        TeachingLecturerId other = (TeachingLecturerId) obj;
        if (lecturerId == null) {
            if (other.lecturerId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lecturerId.equals(other.lecturerId))
            return false;
        if (locationId == null) {
            if (other.locationId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!locationId.equals(other.locationId))
            return false;
        if (teachingId == null) {
            if (other.teachingId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!teachingId.equals(other.teachingId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

and I am getting an error:

```
no.solarsoft.venus2.exception.DataAccessException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.datamanager.DTOFetcher2.fetchDTO(DTOFetcher2.java:74)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.datamanager.DataManager.getTeachingById(DataManager.java:10035)
    at no.solarsoft.test.TeachingDAOTester.createTestTEaching(TeachingDAOTester.java:47)
    at no.solarsoft.test.TeachingDAOTester.testSaveTeaching(TeachingDAOTester.java:39)
    at no.solarsoft.test.TeachingDAOTester.main(TeachingDAOTester.java:24)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2238)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1855)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.isEmpty(PersistentBag.java:249)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.DTO.TeachingLocationDTO.<init>(TeachingLocationDTO.java:37)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.DTO.TeachingDTO.<init>(TeachingDTO.java:62)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.DAO.TeachingDAO.getTeachingDTOById(TeachingDAO.java:79)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.datamanager.DataManager$35.operationsToDo(DataManager.java:10033)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.datamanager.DataManager$35.operationsToDo(DataManager.java:1)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.datamanager.DTOFetcher2.fetchDTO(DTOFetcher2.java:66)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "TEACHINGLE0_"."TEACHINGID": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:861)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1145)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1267)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3493)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    ... 30 more
```

What did I forget to put in annotation? I tried using JoinColumns but it didn't still work.

Thanks!

Comment: What's `TEACHINGLE0_`?

Comment: I don't know. It have TEACHINGLE0_ neither in the code nor database :/

Comment: Do you have a table in DB with similar name?

Comment: no, I only have TEACHING_LECTURER, TEACHING_LOCATION, and TEACHING_DEFINITION, and TEACHING